# What does "Bastion of righteousness" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage

I heard someone use this to describe star wars Obi Wan Kenobi. I know it must mean the quality of being morally right or justifiable but can you define it more specifically.

Comment: First show us what you found in a dictionary.

Comment: It's not a special phrase, it's just the combination of the meanings of each word. Also, it's a bit flowery which means it is a little unclear exactly what is intended but you got most  of it. It would be helped by having a lot more context (the sentence/paragraph that this phrase is in). Is it about Obi Wan? Is it about the whole Star Wars series? Is it about Obi Wan at the moment he surrenders to Darth Vader? etc etc etc

Comment: [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bastion) has perhaps the best definition of the metaphorical sense of 'bastion'. But use M-W say for the prototypical sense.

Comment: The phrase is not a complement about being morally right, it's a statement of being too sure about yourself. Big shot. Preachy.

Comment: If [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bastion+of+piety%2Cbastion+of+righteousness&year_start=1910&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=10) is to be believed, *bastions of **righteousness*** have been edging out near-synonymous *bastions of **piety*** over the last few decades. But all three nouns just have their dictionary definitions (or trivial metaphoric extensions therefrom), so I don't see why the matter needs to be queried here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastion: From French *bastillon*, diminutive of Old French *bastille* "fortress, tower, fortified building.

By fortress this means the protector of what is right, traditional or orthodox. It is almost by definition a subjective idea. It is also by definition overwrought, that is, more than is needed to describe the situation.